# WCF service hosted on IIS7.5 when accessing database trhows error 400 bad request

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have a wcf service that has a method which returns List after collecting information from SQL Server 2008 based database. While working in developement mode there is absolutly no problem, but when I run the service on IIS and try to access the method that is getting information from the database, the browser returns: "bad request 400". When I call a method that is not working with databases it succeeds.

I am really desperate - I serached and searched, tried different things but nothing worked.
Thank you,

Comment: Turn on WCF tracking http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx and check the real exception causing this problem.

Comment: I tried to add log but i can't seem to make it. Maybe it's the connection string that is the problem. I will try to attach log again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost assuredly a permissions problem. Without knowing your specific setup, here are some things to look for:

1. If using Windows Authentication to your SQL Server database, make sure that the identity used by your service's app pool has the correct permissions to the SQL Server database/tables/etc.
2. If using SQL Authentication to your SQL Server database, make sure that the username/password is correct in the connection string and that permissions are setup correctly in the database.

Unless you are using impersonation or have specified a specific user at your site level in IIS, it's likely one of the above.

My guess is that you are using Windows Authentication to connect to your SQL Server database and you have not [specified an App Pool Identity](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/). My advice is to use a specific account for your app pool (domain\username) and then give that account the proper database permissions.

You also should [configure tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to capture the real exception.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set permission to the database.

Comment: I set up tracing and got the error "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'."

Comment: Yep, that's what I suspected. You should configure your app pool to run as a specific domain account. See the link in my answer.

Comment: I looked through it and did as the screenshots suggested still the same result :( Am I doing something wrong. Thank you for the answers though.

Comment: Well it's a two step process: the first is to setup the app pool with the identity that you want to use, the second is make sure that identity (whichever Identity you setup in the first step) has the correct permissions in SQL Server.

Comment: when I add the App pool to SQL server it says that that app pool does not exists.

Comment: Use a domain account: yourDomainName\someusername.

Comment: Problem solved: I had to give permission not only to the database but to tables too... Thank you.